# how to use plink and expect simultaneously

Tags: tcl, expect, plink

I'm using plink and expect to connect with server from Windows. I've created a text widget .l1 to see what's going on durign connection. Normally when I use this:

```
catch {exec plink.exe -ssh myserver} res
.l1 insert 1.0 $res
```

I recieve in a .l1 text widget: "password: " which means that plink works, it is connecting with server and asking me for password.

When I'm using spawn in place of exec:

```
catch {spawn plink.exe -ssh myserver} res
expect "password: "
.l1 insert 1.0 $res
exp_send "exit"
```

I recieve some random digits like 1482 or 4584. Why it's not working?

Comment: That is the process id of the plink process. What do you want to display?

Comment: I want to be sure that plink is working and expect is responding well at this stage. Normally plink is working in background and I see nothing. Why it's returning me id process and not the respond - question for a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expect remembers what it has seen. I highly recommend reading the "Exploring Expect" book.

Something like this (untested) should help:

```
spawn plink.exe -ssh myserver
expect "password: "
.l1 insert 1.0 $expect_out(buffer)
exp_send "password\r"
expect "my_shell_prompt$ "
.l1 insert end $expect_out(buffer)
... etc
```